# How to create the divide method in Python

Tags: python, class, methods

How do I create the divide method in Python?

This is my code:

```
# Rational numbers

def gcd(bigger, smaller):
    '''compute the greatest common divisor of two positive integers'''
    #print(' in gcd ')
    if not bigger > smaller :
        bigger, smaller = smaller, bigger
    while smaller != 0:
        remainder = bigger % smaller
        #print('gcd calc, big:{}, small:{}, rem:{}'.format(bigger, smaller, remainder))
        bigger, smaller = smaller, remainder
    return bigger

def lcm(a, b):
    '''calculate the least common multiple of two positive integers'''
    #print(' in lcm ')
    return (a*b)//gcd(a,b)


class Rational(object):
    '''Rational with numerator and denominator. Denominator defaults to 1'''

    def __init__(self, numer, denom = 1):
        #print('in constructor')
        self.numer = numer
        self.denom = denom

    def __str__(self):
        '''String representation for printing'''
        #print(' in str ')
        return str(self.numer)  + '/'  +  str(self.denom)

    def __repr__(self):
        ''' Used in the interpreter. Call __str__ for now'''
        print(' in repr ')
        return self.__str__()

    def __add__(self, param_Rational):
        '''Add two Rationals'''
        if type(param_Rational) == int:
            param_Rational = Rational(param_Rational)
        if type(param_Rational) == Rational:
            # find the lcm
            the_lcm = lcm(self.denom, param_Rational.denom)
            # multiply each numerator by the lcm, then add
            numerator_sum = the_lcm*self.numer/self.denom + \
                        the_lcm*param_Rational.numer/param_Rational.denom
            return Rational( int(numerator_sum), the_lcm )
        else:
            print("Wrong type in addition method.")
            raise(TypeError)

    def __sub__(self, param_Rational):
        '''Subtract two Rationals'''
        #print(' in add ')
        # find the lcm
        the_lcm = lcm(self.denom, param_Rational.denom)
        # multiply each numerator by the lcm, then add
        numerator_sum = the_lcm*self.numer/self.denom - \
                    the_lcm*param_Rational.numer/param_Rational.denom
        return Rational( int(numerator_sum), the_lcm )

    def reduce_rational(self):
        '''Return the reduced fraction value as a Rational'''
        # find the gcd and divide numerator and denominator by it
        the_gcd = gcd(self.numer, self.denom)
        return Rational( self.numer//the_gcd, self.denom//the_gcd)

    def __eq__(self, param_Rational):
        '''Compare two Rationals for equalit and return a Boolean'''
        reduced_self  = self.reduce_rational()
        reduced_param = param_Rational.reduce_rational()
        return reduced_self.numer == reduced_param.numer and\
               reduced_self.denom == reduced_param.denom

    def __mul__(self, param_Rational):
        ''' Multiply two Rationals '''
        if type(param_Rational) == int:
            param_Rational = Rational(param_Rational)

        if type(param_Rational) == Rational:
            #multiply
            denom_zero_check = self.denom
            second_denom_zero_check = param_Rational.denom
            if denom_zero_check & second_denom_zero_check > 0:
                numer_mul = self.numer*param_Rational.numer
                denom_mul = self.denom*param_Rational.denom
                return Rational(int(numer_mul),int(denom_mul))
            else:
                print("Denominator can't be zero.")
        else:
            print("Wrong type in subtraction method")
            raise(TypeError)
            """ """

    def __truediv__(self):           # <-------- Here is where TypeError occurs #
        ''' Divide two Rationals '''
        if type(param_Rational) == int:
            param_Rational = Rational(param_Rational)

        if type(param_Rational) == Rational:
            #multiply
            denom_zero_check = self.denom
            second_denom_zero_check = param_Rational.denom
            if denom_zero_check & second_denom_zero_check > 0:
                numer_mul = self.numer*param_Rational.denom
                denom_mul = self.denom*param_Rational.numer
                return Rational(int(numer_mul),int(denom_mul))
            else:
                print("Denominator can't be zero.")
```

And I'm getting the error (location marked above):

```
TypeError: __truediv__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

How do I fix this?  I got the multiplication down but not the divide, should I use `div` or `truediv`?  And do I need to use `/` in the actual `div` method?

Comment: Could you post the error message and indicate the line where the error occurs?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/chan/Desktop/testing multiply.py", line 138, in <module>
    r5 = r3 / r4
TypeError: __truediv__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: It seems you are just posting a whole bunch of code and a somewhat vague error message and you expect other users to provide a ready to use fix. The format of SO is perhaps not the best suited one for this. Be more specific. On first sight you are somehow calling trued() with the wrong arguments, a relatively basic mistake.

Comment: im trying to divide but i get different errors, using div or trued so im not sure which one to use and how to fix the error

Comment: I'm surprised this hasn't been closed as a duplicate yet.

Answer (score 4):

How can `__truediv__` only take one argument? You need two, `self` and the divisor. The same way your `__mul__` `__add__`, and `__sub__` needed a second argument.

```
def __truediv__(self, param_Rational):
    # rest of your code
```

Comment: if i use __truediv__ i get nothing as an answer when i do r5 = r3/r4

Comment: @ChAnChaoSae: There are code paths in your `__truediv__()` method were it doesn't return anything (which effectively makes it return `None`). In such cases you should instead raise an exception.

Comment: i forgot that, THANKS!

Comment: i did it but my answer im getting with truediv is wrong its 1/1 instead of 1/81 when i do 2/3 / 6/9

Answer (score 0):

Instead of first printing an error message and then raising the error, you can use:

```
raise TypeError("Wrong type in addition method.")
```

Also, it might be usefull to check wether the demnominator is 0 or not in **init**(), and raise ZeroDivisionError if it  is.

PS: 2/3 / 6/9 should equal 1/1 as 2/3=6/9=0.666...